# How to curve a small part in a circular cardview in android to show the online status icon occupy at the bottom

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, android-cardview

I have used circular cardview to show the user status as online. But the circular has a small curve to occupy the status enable icon.

How can I acheive this in android. My code shows the circular image.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        >
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_online_status"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_green_posts"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Username">
    </TextView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly, all you need to do is to put this inside some kind of parent layout (Relative, Constraint). Then simply put this circular shape to the bottom right, and above the card view.